# Installing Joint State publisher, its GUI and URDF tutorial

Tags: joint-state-publisher, windows10, urdf-tutorial, ros-iron

I have been learning how to use ROS2 from the webpage's tutorials. I am currently using Windows 10 and Iron Irwini. I have been able to go through quite a number of them and I just got to the URDF tutorials. I am having issues installing the joint_state_publisher. I had to clone the github repo using the link given. I visited the github, copied the URL and cloned it. After that I am facing the difficulty of building and running it.
This is the error, I get anytime I try to build it. I have changed the directories to several ones and it still doesn't work.

```
C:\ros2_ws\src>colcon build --merge-install --packages-select joint_state_publisher
Starting >>> joint_state_publisher
--- stderr: joint_state_publisher
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any
  of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


---
Failed   <<< joint_state_publisher [2.72s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [5.98s]
  1 package failed: joint_state_publisher
  1 package had stderr output: joint_state_publisher
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)
```

It seems to be about catkin, and I do not know how to make it work.
I would be grateful for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to check out the appropriate branch of the joint state publisher repo. For Iron I believe you should check out the `ros2` branch.

The default branch is for ROS Noetic and expects Catkin.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful. I have been able to build it now.

Another issue which now popped up is with a missing urdf file, although I followed all the steps correctly.